# Move files with same name in different folders to one folder

Tags: find, mv

I have multiple folders that represent a participant, and each of them have a file called **con_0001.img**. I would like to move all those files (**con_0001.img**) to one new folder (rather than having them in individual participant folders).

The code below seems to find **con_0001.img** and moves it to a new folder, called **SA_A**:

`find . -name "con_0001.img" -exec mv '{}' "./SA_A/" ";"`

However, as all the files are named `con_0001.img`, I end up with just the one file in my new folder (presumably because all subsequent files overwrite each other).

I did manage to find a suggestion for preventing this overwriting, namely:

`find . -name "con_0001.img" -exec mv --backup=numbered "{}" "./SA_A/" \;`

However, I still end up with the one file and **con_0001.img** has disappeared from multiple folders, so it seems to be overwriting. If I change `mv` to `cp`, I also end up with the one file (but the files stay where they are, as you would expect for copying files).

Is there a way of avoiding this overwriting? And more ideally, is there a way of adding part of the name of its parent directory (participant number) to the file when it is moved to the new folder? For example:

> p102/con_0001.img ----> p102_con_0001.img
>
> p105/con_0001.img ----> p105_con_0001.img

I tried the adapt the following code, as it seems that it should add the parent directory to the moved file:

`find . -name 'con_0001.img' | while read filePath; do cp "$filePath" './SA_A'/"$(echo "$filePath")"; done`

However, it returns an error:

> cannot create regular file '/SA_A/./p105/con_0001.img': no such file or directory

There appears to be an unexpected full stop after my new folder **/SA_A/.** which probably is the reason why the code does not work? Where is this full stop is coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir SA_A
find . -name "con_0001.img" -exec sh -c '
    for f; do d=${f%/*}; mv -- "$f" "./SA_A/${d#./}${f##*/}"; done
' findsh {} +
```

The for loop loops over each found file.

- `d=${f%/*}` removes the rightmost `/*` part of `f`, i.e., the basename of the file.
- `${d#./}` removes the leading `./` of the file.
- `${f##*/}` gets the basename of the file, removing everything before the last `/`.

Before execution:

```
$ ls a1 a2 a3
a1:
con_0001.img

a2:
con_0001.img

a3:
con_0001.img
```

After execution:

```
$ ls a1 a2 a3 SA_A/
a1:

a2:

a3:

SA_A/:
a1con_0001.img  a2con_0001.img  a3con_0001.img
```

But it is even simpler with a single shell loop:

```
for f in */con_0001.img; do
    mv -- "$f" "./SA_A/${f%/*}_${f#*/}"
done
```